# Tell IntelliJIdea to use specific JDK version, not just JDK8, but jdk-8u201

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, pom.xml

After a switch to JDK8 the MANIFEST.MF Attributes started returning `null`
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8201636 suggests that this is a bug introduced by Oracle in JDK 8u151-8u172.

I use pom.xml and IntelliJ IDEA. `pom.xml` specifies (tags `<` and `>` removed)

```
<maven.compiler.target> 1.8 </maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source> 1.8 </maven.compiler.source>
```

IDEA settings show `target bytecode version 1.8`
`JAVA_HOME` set to JDK10
I have `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201` installed.

How to specify this version for the builds. Also does `pom.xml` trump IDEA project settings or vice versa?

---

Edit:
I've specified

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <!--executable>{JAVA_1_8_HOME}/bin/javac</executable-->
                <executable>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/javac</executable>
                <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Intellij still defaults to JDK 1.5 and chokes on `List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();` with "I don't understand <> with JDK1.5".

Answer (score 0):

`maven.compiler.target` and `source` are nothing to do with it. Those are just [arguments passed to `javac`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

If you want to specify the version of `javac` explicitly, you can use [the Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html).

```
<configuration>
  <verbose>true</verbose>
  <fork>true</fork>
  <executable><!-- path-to-javac --></executable>
  <compilerVersion>1.3</compilerVersion>
</configuration>
```

Otherwise the `javac` from the Project SDK will be used (Project Structure > Project).

Comment: If you don't mind, can you look at this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520594/jdk-version-hierarchy-in-ideamaven-what-is-the-order-of-importance-of-jdk-sett