# JDK version hierarchy in IDEA+Maven: What is the order of importance of JDK setters

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, pom.xml

So far, I find these places talking about JDK version

1. Settings -> Java Compiler -> Project Bytecode
2. Project Settings -> Modules -> Sources and set language level
3. `.idea/compiler.xml: <module name="my_module" target="1.8" />`
4. Windows `JAVA_HOME`
5. `pom.xml`

   ```
   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   ```

After setting each of them to JDK8 the compiler still defaults to 1.5 and fails

```
Error:(59, 21) java: try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
```

Three questions:
What are the other hidden places to set JDK version?
Which setting wins if each place has a different setting?
How to specify not just JDK8, but JDK8u201?

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise. There is no order of precedence. IntelliJ automatically populates those values from the POM. If you change them in the project and then re-import the POM (the little circular arrow button in the Maven panel) then the ones in the IntelliJ project settings will revert back to how they are in the POM.

Comment: There is a top-level project language level at Project Settings > Project > Project language level that you have not mentioned but, again, this is driven by the POM.